# Pick and print a certain group of integers out of an array

Tags: c, arrays, grouping

Let's say that we have an array with the temperatures of a whole month typed by the user.

```
int april[31];
int i;

for(i=0; i<31; i++)
{
    printf("Give today's temperature: \n");
    scanf("%d", &april[i]);
}

for(i=0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("Day %d  = %dC\n", i+1, april[i]);
```

Next, the user types two numbers (days of the month, <=31 && >0), which the program will show on the screen the temperatures between those numbers. Example:

```
GIVE A SPACE OF 2 DAYS SO I'LL SHOW YOU THE TEMPS(1-31):
>>2 10
THE TEMPS ARE: 28, 25, 23, 27, 26, 25, 24, 29, 30
```

Should I just make a new array for them, or is there any way to kind of "snatch" a group of consecutive array values and print them?

Comment: If all you want to do is print then -- just use `printf` in a for-loop controlled by the numbers entered by the user.

Comment: 'for(i=0; i<31; i++)' do you understand 'i=0' and 'i<31' mean?  If you change that initialization and condition, you can achieve your aim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int start, end;
printf("GIVE A SPACE OF 2 DAYS SO I'LL SHOW YOU THE TEMPS(1-31):");
scanf("%d %d", &start, &end);
for (int k = start - 1; k < end - 1; k++) {
    printf("%d ", april[k]);
}
```